# Contract function returns address?

Tags: contract-invocation, addresses

Learning ethereum, I am hoping this is an easy one. I wrote a simple test contract

```
contract Mini{
uint balance;

// constructor
// runs once upon creation
function Mini(){
    balance = 1000;
}

function deposit(uint _value) returns(uint _newValue){
    balance += _value;
    return balance;
}

function benchmark() returns(uint _newValue){
    return 4545;
}}
```

When I invoke "benchmark"

```
    var result = myContractInstance.benchmark(function(err,res){
        console.log(res);
    });
```

The response is an address (e.g. 0xd1d618bcb179db8b020358710138d1a008f4f39e). I can see the transaction in etherscan. Question, how do I see the response value?

Answer (score 0):

benchmark is not a constant function so it will return a transaction id for you.

if you need to return a value or read a value from block chain you can use constant function

`function benchmark() public  constant returns(uint _newValue){
    return 4545;
}}`

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. However, in the case where you want the result of the function call, the one identified by the transaction. How do you see it?

Comment: I just verified I can call the constant function and get the expect return value, 4545. Question, how do I get the response from the "deposit" function? What do I do with the address?

Comment: While the return value is available to other contracts, it is not possible for an external observer to get the return value of a state-changing transaction. You can use the returned receipt to wait for the transaction to be mined, then a few options: Inspect the transaction log, inspect another function, replay the transaction (that's how Remix does it).

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I was missing "constant" and "view". Here is the final contract:

```
contract Mini{
    uint balance;

    // constructor
    function Mini(){
        balance = 1000;
    }

    function deposit(uint _value) public returns(uint _newValue){
        balance += _value;
        return balance;
    }

    function withdraw(uint _value) view  returns(uint _newValue){
        balance -= _value;
        return balance;
    }

    function benchmark() public  constant returns(uint _newValue){
        return 4545;
    }

    function getBalance() public constant returns(uint _newValue){
       return balance;
    } 
}
```

I was then able call the functions as follows:

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('YourContractAddress');


myContractInstance.benchmark(function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
});

myContractInstance.deposit(200,function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
});

myContractInstance.withdraw(50,function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
});

myContractInstance.getBalance(function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: To update this question, constant keyword has been removed from solidity 0.5.0. One should use pure or view instead.